# Cap'n proto generated c++ source doesn't compile

Tags: c++, capnproto

I'm having trouble with this piece of capnp code:

```
struct Result(Success, Error) {
    union {
        success @0 :Success;
        error   @1 :Error;
    }
}
```

I created and compiled the c++ source like this:

```
capnp compile -oc++ test.capnp
g++ -o test.capnp.o test.capnp.c++ `pkg-config --cflags capnp` -std=c++11
```

And I'm getting this same error (and the same with ERROR instead of SUCCESS) at multiple locations in the generated header file:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class Success, class Error> struct Result’
   KJ_IREQUIRE(which() == Result<Success, Error>::SUCCESS,
   ^
error:   expected a type, got ‘true’
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   KJ_IREQUIRE(which() == Result<Success, Error>::SUCCESS,
                                               ^
error: ‘::SUCCESS’ has not been declared
   KJ_IREQUIRE(which() == Result<Success, Error>::SUCCESS,
                                                ^
```

Here is one of the definitions that g++ complains about:

```
template <typename Success, typename Error>
inline  ::capnp::ReaderFor<Success> Result<Success, Error>::Reader::getSuccess() const {
  KJ_IREQUIRE(which() == Result<Success, Error>::SUCCESS,
              "Must check which() before get()ing a union member.");
  return ::capnp::_::PointerHelpers<Success>::get(
      _reader.getPointerField(0 * ::capnp::POINTERS));
}
```

I really don't understand why g++ doesn't accept this...

I use capnproto 0.5.3 (first encountered this issue in 0.5.2 and then updated to see if that would help) and g++ 4.9.2.

Comment: Ah, you've already submitted an issue (https://github.com/sandstorm-io/capnproto/issues/233). Good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The rest of this answer is outdated. This issue should not appear anymore since capnp version 0.6.0.**

---

Just when I was done writing my question, I wanted to test this with clang as well, and it actually made me find the error. I still chose to post the question as I was already done writing. The problem is that `KJ_IREQUIRE` is a macro, and as macros are a thing the preprocessor handles, their semantics are very ugly. The comma in the template arguments for `Result` gets interpreted as an argument delimiter for the macro, leading to this really unhelpful error message in g++, but a much nicer one in clang.

To work around this, you can add another set of brackets around the arguments of `KJ_IREQUIRE`. I hope this bit of documentation can help someone!